# Convert all Solidworks files in folder to step files macro

Tags: macros, solidworks, converters, step

I was searching around and looking for a macro that will when run it will convert the files in the location into .stp files and I came across the below. how can i manipulate it to grab the next file in the folder and continue the next files and convert them until all the files have been converted.

```
Dim swApp               As Object
```

Dim Part                As Object

Dim FilePath            As String

Dim sFilePath           As String

Dim PathSize            As Long

Dim PathNoExtention     As String

Dim NewFilePath         As String

Dim FileLocation        As String

Dim sPath               As String

Dim i                   As Long

Dim bRebuild            As Boolean

Dim bRet                As Boolean

Dim sRev                As String

Dim nErrors             As Long

Dim nWarnings           As Long

Sub main()

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc

FilePath = Part.GetPathName

PathSize = Strings.Len(FilePath)

sPath = Left(Part.GetPathName, InStrRev(Part.GetPathName, "\"))

sRev = Part.CustomInfo("re") 'Change Configuration Property name here

FileLocation = "C:"

PathNoExtension = Strings.Left(FilePath, PathSize - 7)

Part.SaveAs (PathNoExtension & "rev" & sRev & ".step")

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this a few different ways if you're not using a VB6 Macro. If you use a .NET Macro (Visual Basic or C#), they support .NET libraries which makes this process quite simple. I've created the following Console Application in C#. You could create the same thing as a .NET Macro in SolidWorks. The important thing to add to the example you provided is the foreach statement which will iterate over all of the files in the directory and only perform the translation on SolidWorks Parts or Assemblies.

```
using SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CreateStepFiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static SldWorks swApp;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string directoryName = GetDirectoryName();

            if (!GetSolidWorks())
            {
                return;
            }

            int i = 0;

            foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(directoryName))
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower() == ".sldprt")
                {
                    CreateStepFile(fileName, 1);
                    i += 1;
                }
                else if (Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower() == ".sldasm")
                {
                    CreateStepFile(fileName, 2);
                    i += 1;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished converting {0} files", i);

        }

        static void CreateStepFile(string fileName, int docType)
        {
            int errors = 0;
            int warnings = 0;

            ModelDoc2 swModel = swApp.OpenDoc6(fileName, docType, 1, "", ref errors, ref warnings);

            string stepFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), ".STEP");

            swModel.Extension.SaveAs(stepFile, 0, 1, null, ref errors, ref warnings);

            Console.WriteLine("Created STEP file: " + stepFile);;

            swApp.CloseDoc(fileName);
        }

        static string GetDirectoryName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory to Converty");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Directory.Exists(s))
            {
                return s;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Directory does not exists, try again");
            return GetDirectoryName();
        }

        static bool GetSolidWorks()
        {
            try
            {
                swApp = (SldWorks)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SldWorks.Application"));

                if (swApp == null)
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(swApp));
                }

                if (!swApp.Visible)
                {
                    swApp.Visible = true;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("SolidWorks Loaded");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not launch SolidWorks");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy I will give this a shot. If I wanted to use a different file type let’s parasolid, all I would have to do is change the step function and fit it for parasolid?

Comment: You can change the function to accept a parameter that is the extension of the file.

For example, change the method to 
static void CreateStepFile(string filename, int docType, string extension)
{
  string stepFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), ".", extension);
}

Comment: Can you please tell me how to run this file - I mean how to set development environment and get the functionality running, any references to it etc.

Comment: This helped me A LOT! Thanks!

When I tried it though I was getting:
Created STEP file: C:\blah\blah\blah\3259T612_Strut Channel Nut\.STEP
Couldn't figure out the "right way" to do it but I did get it working by putting 


`string stepFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".STEP");`